# Some component of my computer does not have a driver for windows 10 yet?

Tags: windows-10-upgrade

While waiting for my windows 10 upgrade, I get the following:

> We're working with our partners to make sure that windows 10 is ready for your particular PC.  When you get your notification, it means that you can proceed with  your upgrade.

Details:

> Critical Hardware components made by Intel for your pc don't have drivers for windows 10 yet.

Does anyone know where I can go to get information about this?  I tried going to intel and HP (who made my computer) and did not see anywhere where I can get that info.

Comment: What are the specifications of your computer? You would just google the model or components.

Comment: Post your exact model of HP please.

Answer (score 2):

It's possible to find out what what component is causing the problem. Try left clicking one of the 'Get Windows 10' options, then click the 3 horizontal lines in the top left. This lets you select the 'Check your PC' option. From there there's a 'Details' button. In my case it was my Antivirus program that it thought was an Intel component.

Answer (score 1):

To check Windows 10 upgrade compatibility, follow these steps:

1. Download and install KB3035583 (https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/3035583) to get the Get Windows 10 app
2. In the Get Windows 10 app, click menu (stack of three lines) and then select Check your PC
3. Review the list of potential compatibility issues. Separate categories are listed for devices and apps

That will provide a list of components not currently supported by Windows 10. Follow up with the manufacture of the components to acquire the appropriate drivers.

Answer (score 0):

I had this error on my PC, which has a MSI motherboard, Haswell CPU and no dedicated GPU.

I searched the MSI site and found Windows 10 versions of all the drives, so went ahead and did the install.

Go to https://www.microsoft.com/en-gb/software-download/windows10 and download the install tool. Then choose to install on this PC. It will reboot a couple of times, but then should work a treat.

Comment: Just to clarify, the Microsoft link is just to manually upgrade to Win 10 after you have found the relevant drivers?  Can you explain the procedure for making use of the drivers to enable the Win 10 upgrade (do you install them on your earlier Windows, then upgrade and Win 10 uses them, or the manual upgrade bypasses the warning and installs a non-functional Win 10, after which you load the drivers you previously downloaded)?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same thing on a Acer Aspire 753 netbook. From Windows 7 Home
intel critical hardware components so could not upgrade.

Did all the windows updates, Intel auto updater did not say anything needed updating but still says I could not upgrade. So I made an image backup just in case and installed Win 10 from a download. win 10 help/faq's (somewhere about installing on multiple computers) it lets you download whatever version you need, pro or home, 32 or 64bit to a USB stick.
Installed easy & fast (under 2 hours'ish) without any problems & seems to be running fine although only had on for a few hours.

Answer (score -1):

From Windows Device Manager, get the properties of the Device..

Then, go to http://pcidatabase.com

Enter in the code with the entry for VEN for Vendor and DEV for Device.

For example: VEN_8086 and you would just search using 8086 and the result is the Vendor Intel..

Good luck!

Comment: I am confused as to why I am being downvoted.